# Magento 2 - How to automatically regenerate sequence tables?

Tags: magento2, migration, sequence

The situation is: some dude at my workplace migrated the project's database to a new server and somehow, some sequence tables such as `sequence_order_xx`, `sequence_invoice_xx` and so on, are missing during the process. After that, he quit the job and I'm the one who take care of the project next.

Because those tables are missing, we can't checkout in all corresponding stores (about 20 stores) with this error message:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query was: INSERT INTO `` () VALUES ()
```

The dude already quit, so I can't check with him to see how the migration process was done. I know that those tables are generated, now they're missing, is there a way to recreate them? I tried reindexing but not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to recreate this tables.

Also sequence for invoice credit memo etc.

This happens in migration and sometimes when you create new store view.

Related with this bug , there is also described how to recreate this tables:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12318